# How can i made an associative array with a variable?

Tags: javascript

How can i made an associative array with a variable?

```
var name = "example";
var array = [];
array.push(name: 1);
```

I want see in to the array example: 1

~Thank you everyone~

Comment: Hi, can you please provide more details?

Comment: An associative array/list is just an object?

Comment: Maybe array.push({name: 1});?

Comment: If you want an array with objects: `array.push({ [name]: 1 });`

Answer (score 1):

An object would fit the bill:

```
var key = "example";
var value = 1;
var dict = {};
dict[key] = value;
```

Comment: This is not JSON; it is simply an object. JSON is a string.

Comment: @user1599011 JSON = Javascript Object Notation

Comment: Fair enough; corrected.

Comment: `Java Script Object Notation` is not the same as an object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON

Comment: I just try array.push({[name]: 1}); and work for me!! 

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var name = "example";
var array = [];
array[name] = 1;
console.log(array[name])
```

Or directly:

```
var name = "example";
var array = { name: 1};
console.log(array[name])
```